# terraform apply trying to destroy launch configuration that is deleted manually

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, autoscaling, destroy, launch-configuration

I've deleted couple of launch configurations from AWS console which I didn't need. Now with an updated terraform script, terraform apply tries to deleted launch configurations that are deleted manually and fails. Prior to terraform apply terraform is accompanied by terraform init and plan.

It gives a validation error with launch configuration not found.

Comment: You should never delete terraform managed resources through the console or cli. Now, you have to delete the state entry - use terraform state rm <terraformId>

Comment: @victorm do you mean the 'aws-resourceId'?

Comment: terraformId aws_config.name